# Add existing project to existing git repository

Tags: git, tfs

I've got a Visual Studio solution already part of a git repository on TFS.  The solution consists of a number of projects.  Everything was fine until recently I renamed one of the projects.  I've noticed that the renamed project has dropped out of the repository and I can't figure out how to get it back in.

Googling reveals a lot of information about adding existing solutions to new git repositories, but I can't find any advice on how to fix the situation I find myself in.  I'm a git noob which certainly isn't helping; I can't even figure out got to call git from the command line.

Surely there's a simple sequence of git commands to get my project back in the repository?

Comment: How did you rename your project. What exactly do you mean by your project has "dropped out" of the repository? What does `git status` say? Is your missing project still in the working directory?

Comment: Hmm, well, I can't really help you with TFS, I only worked with it for a few months ***before*** it ever had any official integration with git. If you want to install msysgit or poshgit so that you can run git's native command line interface, I can help you from there, but otherwise you'll need to wait for someone who knows both git and TFS/Visual Studio well enough to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I'm only using git via TFS.  I renamed my project by right-clicking the project in the solution tree (I think).  It may be coincidental that the project no longer appears as connected to git.
The project icon in the solution tree no longer indicates it is part of source control, and no checkout occur when I edit files in the project.
I used the "install 3rd party tools" to get a git client, which installed "Git GUI" and "Git Bash".  I can't get Git Bash to recognise my repo.  Gui GUI says I have unstaged changes in my renamed project; maybe the VS UI just isn't recognising the project anymore?

Comment: I'm happy to install git clients.  I think git Bash will do what I need; I just can't get it to recognise my repo (probably user error)

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't "recognize" your repo? Did you `cd` into your working directory? Does it contain a `.git` folder? What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: Success!  I managed to cd to the repo and run git status.  It showed me the project dir was unstaged.  I did a git add to the project dir, and git commit to get it in there.
Now VS recognises is as being under source control again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having git integration with both TFS and your Visual Studio IDE sounds nice, but when it comes to trouble-shooting git, sometimes it's best to go directly to git's native command line interface.

Try to `cd` into your solution/project working directory, and check if there's a `.git` folder in there. That represents the git repo for your solution/project. Once you've confirmed that the folder exists, run

```
git status
```

to check the current status of your working copy. If you have untracked files or unstaged changes, you may wish to add them now with

```
git add <filepaths>
```

Make sure that you don't forget to add any related changes to your Visual Studio solution and project files, otherwise Visual Studio may not recognize the changes that you've made.

Once you've staged your files, go ahead and run

```bash
git commit
# or
git commit -m "message"
```

to commit your changes. Then verify that Visual Studio recognizes the changes that you've made to your solution/project.

Comment: Thanks for you help Cupcake.  Understanding some of the basics of git goes a long way in being able to help myself.

Comment: @Zodman you're welcome. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it as well.